# How to do math between two variables in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, variables, math

```
        Select Case lstFlavours.SelectedItem
            Case "Vanilla" Or "Chocolate" Or "Strawberry"
                scoopType = BASIC_FLAVOUR
            Case "Mango" Or "Bananna" Or "Grape" Or "Mint Chocolate Chip"
                scoopType = PREMIUM_FLAVOUR

                scoopType*txtScoops = runningTotal 

        End Select
```

I would like to do the math with the scoopType * txtScoops which is the number of scoops i have, and add it to my running total

Comment: There's an entire manual on the Visual Basic Programming Language. You should look at it before asking basic questions on the language. See [Visual Basic Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4wf33f0.aspx) . For detailed reference, see the [Reference (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25kad608.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Your [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx) may not give you the results you want when using `Or` in `Case` statements. If you're selecting *individual* items, use a comma.

```
Select Case lstFlavours.SelectedItem
    Case "Vanilla", "Chocolate", "Strawberry"
        scoopType = BASIC_FLAVOUR
    Case "Mango", "Bananna", "Grape", "Mint Chocolate Chip"
        scoopType = PREMIUM_FLAVOUR
End Select
```

Finally, [variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd6hcy37.aspx) assignment requires that the variable being modified be on the left of the operator.

```
runningTotal = scoopType * txtScoops
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your variables are all declared properly, following should be ok:

```
Select Case lstFlavours.SelectedItem
            Case "Vanilla" Or "Chocolate" Or "Strawberry"
                scoopType = BASIC_FLAVOUR
            Case "Mango" Or "Bananna" Or "Grape" Or "Mint Chocolate Chip"
                scoopType = PREMIUM_FLAVOUR
End Select

runningTotal = scoopType*Double.Parse(txtScoops.text)
```

Comment: Okay so now I did that, I got the error Operator '*' is not defined for types 'Double' and 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'. How would I make the Textbox parse into a Double

Comment: @JoeyMacleod. Using `Double.Parse(Textbox1.Text)` should do the parsing bit for you.

Comment: @Bababarghi - Please edit your answer to include the `Double.Parse(Textbox1.Text)`.

Comment: @Enigmativity He has not given enough information about his variables but I tried to do my best guess out of it

Comment: Okay now another question this one is unrealated to the last bit of code; I keep getting an error trying to output my total amount into my label. FormatCurrency(Double.Parse(lblOutputTotal.Text) = runningTotal)  @Bababarghi

Comment: @JoeyMacleod - If you have another question then ask it as a new question. Please do not impose on people who have already answered - it's not the right etiquette here. You can, however, post a link to your new question as a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

he said "add" it to his running total, so do you want it like this?:

```
runningTotal += scoopType*Double.Parse(txtScoops.text)
```

and @Justin Ryan is right, use commas instead of OR in your SELECT CASE